# Trying to find root mean square of two rows in array

Tags: c++

i am working through an EDX course on computer programming. I have come to this problem and dont know how to work through it. im not looking for an answer but more a point in the right direction.

so the question gives you a 2D array. two columns and N amount of rows. the N is the number of students. each column is the grade of first test and then the second is the grade of the second test. I am asked to find the root mean square of two seperate kids and compare them and then return a number based off the comparison. The question gives you this formula

RMS = (0.5×(midsem_marks<sup>2</sup> + endsem_marks<sup>2</sup>))<sup>0.5</sup>

I know how to get the appropriate marks using array[index 1(firsttest)] etc and then how to compare them. However, i am clueless on how to write that formula. any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

code I have

```
float RMSi1 = sqrt(.5*((marksarray[index1][0]*marksarray[index1][0])+(marksarray[index1][1])*(marksarray[index1][1])));
float RMSi2 = sqrt(.5*((marksarray[index2][0]*marksarray[index2][0])+(marksarray[index2][1])*(marksarray[index2][1])));

if(RSMi1>RSMi2){
    return -1;
}
if(RSMi1<RSMi2){
    return 1;
}
if(RSMi1==RSMi2){
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error that the RSMi1 and 2 are not declared in the if statements
`Input marksarray:
    1   2
1   60  20

2   60  20

3   30  40

4   10  90

5   90  30

6   0   100 
7   60  20`

Comment: Can you show what you've got so far?  We can help you work through some details of the algorithm, but without any code at all this question is too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: You are almost certainly expected to use loops and an exponentiation function, but the error stated is merely due to a typo.

Comment: haha yea, i found it right after i posted it. it works for all the 1s and -1s but for the 0s it returns numbers like -1658420280. any thoughts?

Comment: I've  already expressed some thoughts, and you can't rationally expect people to comment on your result values without knowing the input values.

Comment: Voted to close as simple typo (RSM instead of RMS).

Comment: input`Input marksarray:
 1 2
1 60 20 
2 60 20 
3 30 40 
4 10 90 
5 90 30 
6 0 100 
7 60 20`

Comment: i know there was a typo i fixed and now it complies but it also returns a garbage number for the last if statement. if i leave it blank as an else statement a 0 is returned or if i ask it to return 1 it does, but not 0. iam confused.

Comment: Use a couple of functions `float rms(int a, int b){ return sqrt(0.5*(a*a+b*b))}` and then to compare `float rms1=rms(markarray[i][0],marksarray[i][1]); float rms2=rms(marksarray[j][0],marksarray[j][1]); if (rms1 < rms2) return -1; if (rms1>rms2) return 1; return 0;`. How have you declared/initialized/passed marksarray?

Comment: Comparing `float`s could be tricky, due to rounding errors, but it's not the case of your example data. Without seeing your actual code is not possible to determine the exatct issue (apart from the typo in the posted snippet). [Here](https://ideone.com/FSiiqM) you can see a working example.